# Bazel builds from scratch ignoring cache

Tags: bazel

I observe that my Bazel build agent frequently builds the project from scratch (including compiling grpc, which keeps unchanged) instead of taking results from cache. Is there a way, like query or cquery (pardon my ignorance) to determine why is the cache considered invalid for particular target? Or any techniques to tackle cache invalidation problem?

Comment: It showed that the problem was with instable PATH. To debug it I enabled the `-s` flag which prints executed commands. It showes that Bazel commands are preceeded with `env - PATH=...` which voids all env variables excluding PATH. Comparison between PATH gave me hint on how to address it.

Comment: Good article how to debug Bazel caching https://ejameslin.github.io/Bazel-cache-behind-the-scenes/

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the rebuild sensitivity to particular environment variables. Many build actions will read from environment variables and use them to change the outputs. Bazel keeps track of this and will rebuild seemingly unchanged remote targets when your env changes.

To demonstrate this;

- Build grpc (2x ensure it is cached the second time)
- Change the PATH environment variable (your IDE may do this without you knowing)

  - `mkdir ~/bin && export PATH=$PATH:~/bin`
- Rebuild grpc (This should trigger a complete rebuild)

There are a couple helpful flags to combat this rebuild sensitivity, and I'd recommend adding them to your bazelrc.

- [incompatible_strict_action_env](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--incompatible_strict_action_env): Freezes your environment and doesn't source environment variables from your shell.
- [action_env](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--action_env) modify environment variables as needed for you build.

```
# file //.bazelrc

# Don't source environment from shell
build --incompatible_strict_action_env

# Use action_env as needed for your project
build --action_env=CC=clang
```

Answer (score 0):

This is How the [bazel](https://bazel.build/about/intro#bazel-build-process) build works :

```
When running a build or a test, Bazel does the following: Loads the BUILD files relevant to the target. Analyzes the inputs and their dependencies, applies the specified build rules, and produces an action graph. Executes the build actions on the inputs until the final build outputs are produced.
```

If you are having any clear assumptions can you please share the complete details!